# Slim link not working unless a tag is nested within a tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, slim-lang

I am new to slim. Right now this link works fine:

```
a.footer-nav-item--title.accordion-trigger: a href=club_index_path Clubs
```

However, when I take away the extra anchor tag the link no longer works.

```
a.footer-nav-item--title.accordion-trigger href=club_index_path Clubs
```

I have been asked to take away the extra a tag before merging my changes but I can't figure out how to make this link function without it.

Comment: What is your required output in html? should there be an `a` nested inside another?

Answer (score 0):

Your Slim syntax (the second one) is absolutely correct. So it appears that the issue is likely with your CSS and/or JS. Check both the `footer-nav-item--title` and `accordion-trigger` classes for a couple of things:

1. Is `pointer-events` set to `none` in the CSS for either selector?
2. Are there any JS events bound to either of those selectors that is preventing the default action, etc.